# Is there any ways to save image to Salesforce by using Salesforce APEX

Tags: java, image, base64, salesforce, apex

We are integrating WSO2 ESB with Salesforce. We need to **insert image into Salesforce Object**(Lead). Images are downloaded in some directory. i want to know efficient ideas to complete this task.i have some ideas like

1. Convert image to Base64 Encoding, then send request to Salesforce APEX.
2. Insert Image as BLOB into Database,then fetch that BLOB from DB, stores into byte array and finally push that into Salesforce.
   But i don't know best and efficient way to do this. If you have some ideas/possibilities kindly share it to me. 
   **Note:** For writing Salesforce related task, separate SF Team is here. what i need here is ways/possibilities to achieve this task. Java Class also possible.
   Awaiting for your response!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as content version, Now a days Attachments are deprecated.

```
public with sharing class ContentVersionUtil {
public ContentVersionUtil() {
}
public static Id createDocument(Id parentId, String fileName, String data, Id contentDocumentId) {

    ContentVersion versionData = new ContentVersion();
    versionData.ContentLocation = 'S';
    versionData.ContentDocumentId = contentDocumentId;
    versionData.VersionData = Blob.valueOf(data);
    versionData.Title = fileName;
    versionData.PathOnClient = filename;
    insert versionData;

    ContentDocumentLink conDocLink = new ContentDocumentLink();
    conDocLink.ContentDocumentId = [SELECT Id, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentVersion WHERE Id = :versionData.Id].ContentDocumentId;
    conDocLink.LinkedEntityId = parentId;
    conDocLink.ShareType = 'V';
    insert conDocLink;


    return conDocLink.Id;
}

public static Id createDocument(Id parentId, String fileName, String data) {
    return createDocument(parentId, fileName, data, NULL);
}
public static Id createDocumentafterformat(Id parentId, String fileName, String data) {
    return createDocument(parentId, fileName, data, NULL);
}
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public with sharing class ContentVersionUtilTest {

@TestSetup
static void makeData(){
    Account acc = new Account (Name = 'Test Account');
    insert acc;
    Contact cont = new Contact (LastName = 'Raj', AccountId = acc.Id);
    insert cont;
}
@isTest
static void test_content_version_creation_0 () {
    Contact eachContact = [SELECT Id from Contact LIMIT 1];

    ContentVersionUtil util = new ContentVersionUtil ();
    Id conDocLinkId = ContentVersionUtil.createDocument(eachContact.Id, 'testFile', 'csv', 'Some important Data');
    System.assertEquals(eachContact.Id, [SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId from ContentDocumentLink WHERE Id =: conDocLinkId].LinkedEntityId);
}
}
```